# How to display dataframe without break in Tkinter app

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

Im using code bellow to display `pandas` dataframe, but in my tkinter app i get columns displayed and splited with `'\'`

```
  def on_show_frame(self, event):
            T = tk.Text(self, height=30, width=120, wrap=None)
            T.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=14, rowspan=14, padx=10, pady=10)
            T.insert(tk.END, self.controller.df)
```

Is there option to add to tk.Text to fix this problem? Soo data is displayed without break.

Here is how it looks in my app ,data display is contionued after all rows:

```
              datetime      mean       std  sum   1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  \
0   2017-07-12 08:00:00  1.805556  2.447383   65   8  9  1  0  0  2  0   0  0   
1   2017-07-12 08:01:00  0.833333  1.133893   30   0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0  0   
2   2017-07-12 08:02:00  1.027778  1.182881   37   0  0  1  0  0  2  0   2  0   
3   2017-07-12 08:03:00  0.944444  1.286067   34   0  0  1  0  0  0  0   1  0 


     10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  \
0     0   0   3   1   0   3   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   3   0   0   2   0   
1     0   1   2   4   0   3   1   2   0   1   0   0   2   4   0   2   2   0   
2     1   1   3   0   0   3   1   2   1   2   1   0   2   3   0   2   0   0   
3     1   1   2   1   0   3   1   3   0   1   1   0   2   4   0   0   4   0
```

etc.

```
238   1   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
239   1   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   
240   0   4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   

     28  29  30  31  32  
0     0   3   1   1   2  
1     0   1   1   1   1
```

Than you for all help in advance.

Comment: This is a pandas feature; it has nothing to do with tkinter. It's designed to allow you to print the dataframe in a standard 80-character terminal. Try using `to_string()` instead: `T.insert(tk.END, self.controller.df.to_string())`

Comment: Thank you for solution!